# Cannot join Pandas dataframes on object column

Tags: python, join, pandas

The first dataframe (named df1) is the following one (head):

```
                                         id  vn                  t        pt
0  00000408662094209082085855047091571768_1   1   8/2/2016 9:52:32  category   
1  00000408662094209082085855047091571768_2   2  8/2/2016 10:28:31  category   
2  00000408662094209082085855047091571768_2   2  8/2/2016 10:29:11  category   
3  00000408662094209082085855047091571768_2   2  8/2/2016 10:29:17      home   
4  00000408662094209082085855047091571768_2   2  8/2/2016 10:29:31      home
```

and the second (named df2) is:

```
                                            id  c
14    00001087349068450135050866198201095168_1  1
37   00001894928540859901831574112552100393_10  1
179   00009266881488061960012264744075831635_7  1
302   00010448970554617030262224239139542299_1  1
354   00013397505232083416232379470282942830_1  1
```

When I do:

```
df1.join(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\asterios.BSQ_AD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py:2087: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e8).any()
C:\Users\asterios.BSQ_AD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py:2088: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) &
C:\Users\asterios.BSQ_AD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py:2089: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
(abs_vals > 0)).any()
```

The returning dataframe has values 'NaN' on the new 'c' column although I know that there are ids that match.

For completeness, here is the info of each dataframe:

df1:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 50000 entries, 0 to 49999
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id       50000 non-null object
vn       50000 non-null int64
t        50000 non-null object
pt       40411 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 2.3+ MB
```

df2:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 29300 entries, 14 to 2294263
Data columns (total 2 columns):
id       29300 non-null object
c        29300 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 686.7+ KB
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')` work?

Comment: No, I had tried that as well. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Have you tried dropping any `NaN` rows from both dfs prior to `join`ing?

Comment: There are no Nans before the join in either dataframe